# creating node via javascript throws type error: '.appendChild is not a function'

Tags: javascript

I know there are other seemingly duplicate posts out there but I have not been able to solve my problem. This is my first code and first question on stackoverflow. Please give any pertinent advice for future questions.

I am trying to create an to do list for a class project. First, I don't understand why the error "`appendChild` is not a function" is coming up before I click the "Add" button. Does the browser run through functions before they're called? Second, I could not get the variables to initialize as the elements of the DOM using `querySelector` or even `getElementById` (js lines 1-3), only `getElementsByClassName` worked. On top of that, I need to solve the problem with `appendChild`.

I hope you find this HTML as comical as I did before I started the js portion and frustration set in.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Larry David's Election Day To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="firstMiniCSS.css"></link>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<script src="firstMiniJS.js"></script>

<body>
<h1>Larry David's Election Day To Do List</h1>
<h2>Because voting is impossible when you're Larry David...</h2>

<div class= "toDoList">
  <p>To Do List:</p>
  <ul class="list" id="list">
    <li>Wake up... early. less people vote in the morning</li>
    <li><del datetime="11-08-2016">Check the mail</del> don't check the mail</li>
    <li>Find inconspicuous clothes</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Definitely a hat</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Coffee with whole milk. None of this 2% crap</li>
    <li>Call Richard to ask who he's voting for</li>
    <li>Remember it's very important to vote. You must vote Larry.</li>
    <li>Bring a pen</li>
  </ul>
  <label for="addField">Add something to the list: </label><input type="text" class="addField" placeholder="What would Larry do?"><input type="submit" value="Add" class="addSubmit">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var addField = document.getElementsByClassName('addField');
var submitTask = document.getElementsByClassName('addSubmit');
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list');

var listedTasks = [];

function createTask() {
  if(addField !== ''){
    listedTasks.unshift(addField.value);

    for(var i = 0; i < listedTasks.length; i++) {
      taskText = listedTasks[i];
      var newTask = document.createElement('li');
      newTask.innerHTML = taskText;
      list.appendChild(newTask);
    }
  }
}
submitTask.addEventListener('click', createTask());
```

Thanks

Comment: `list` is a live NodeList, not a dom element so it deosn't have the `appendChild` method

Comment: `var list = document.querySelector('.list');` or `var list = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];`

Comment: Also `submitTask.addEventListener('click', createTask());` should be `submitTask.addEventListener('click', createTask);` - you need to pass a function reference as the click callback